# GetElementById Value in a src tag

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Hi I have the following iFrame and I would like to get the number by ID between SID= and the &ACT can anyone help?

```
<IFRAME  ID=CoachingCaptionFrame SRC=/CRM7Dev/eware.dll/Do?SID=189796409459332&Act=1696&Mode=1&CLk=T&FldCoachingActionID=Act49791Key1&AAct=200  STYLE="display:none;"  ></IFRAME
```

Cheers

Justin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function getSrc() {
var frame = document.getElementById('myframe');
var start = frame.src.indexOf("SID=", 0) + 4;
var end = frame.src.indexOf("&ACT", 0);
var hdnInput = document.getElementById('inputId');
hdnInput.value = frame.src.substring(start, end);
}
```

Haven't tested it but it should work.

Comment: can i then place this value into a hidden input field?

Answer (score 1):

Using jquery,

$('#CoachingCaptionFrame").attr('src').val()

Will get you close, then you can split on a delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = document.getElementById("CoachingCaptionFrame").src;
var matches = str.match(/SID=((.)*)&Act/i);
alert(matches[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the string object's `split()` function to do these kind of stuff(extracting arguments off a URL).

```
var frameSrc = document.getElementById('CoachingCaptionFrame').src;
var SID = frameSrc.split("?")[1].split("&")[0].split("=")[1];
var hiddenInput = document.getElementById("hiddenInputId");
hiddenInput.value = SID;
```